# How to use @SpringApplicationConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

my configurations seems to be right but still refusing to import the spring application configuration

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes= AdminPortalApplication.class)

Answer (score 2):

`@SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotation no longer exists. Replace with this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes =AdminPortalApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Comment: SpringApplicationConfiguration so it is imported it seams my version was the problem I had a higher version but there is a line crossing through the annotation what does that mean @john joe